# How to setup player (which have monetize ability) for video on html5 website

Tags: html, video, html5-video

On my dynamic website I have a lot of video content. Video content I serving from my web server. Now I want to find a way to monetize that content displaying ads on player. My problem is that all platforms for video monetization, which I find for now, are cloud based (you need to upload video on their host and serve link).
So my question is: Is there a way to serve videos from local host (personal web server) and to monetize them? And how?

Comment: if you're using a common player (eg jwplayer) then it doesn't matter where you're hosting content, you can still use VAST and VPAID to add monetization capabilities with pre-roll, post-roll, mid-roll, overlays etc. The bigger challenge/question, unless you have enough traffic to go direct, is how are you planning to sell inventory to advertisers?

Comment: That's part of the question too. I read about players with VAST, VPAID and IMA3 plugins, but where to open some ad account and how to connect player with advertise services (e.g. AdSense, Brightcove or recomand me any)